# How do I fix this terminal error that has to do with AppleEvent

Tags: c#, terminal

For some reason when I was trying to run a simple c# program to run in an external console it comes up as this error:

Unable to launch debugger worker process (vsdbg) through the terminal. /Users/vitocostello/Desktop/Visual StudioCode.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/contrib/externalTerminal/node/TerminalHelper.scpt: execution error: Terminal got an error: AppleEvent timed out. (-1712)

I changed the launch.json "console" to "externalTerminal" so my guess according to the error message that the Terminal is the problem not the actual launch.json file or the program It self

here's the launch.json file if this is what the problem is:

```
{
   // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
   // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
   // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net5.0/LineFeed.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            // For more information about the 'console' field, see https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-Console
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "stopAtEntry": false
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my basic c# code I have written:

```
using System;

namespace LineFeed
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a VSCode problem, not a C# one

Comment: ok how do I fix the VSCode problem

Comment: This may help - https://gist.github.com/whitlockjc/6179b8bf7e92a7b62a07

Comment: I'm not sure how I could apply the link you sent me to help me with my problem.